# Using a variable across c++ programs (compilations)

Tags: c++, variables, ipc

this type of question has been asked several times over here and elsewhere but it seems that I don't get any of the solutions to work. What I've 'accomplished' so far is that a variable can be used by two different applications (one application calls the other one via system command) but the value is NOT passed from the main app to the secondary one.

code corresponds to this:

```
 #ifndef avis_h
    #define avis_h

    #include "string"
    using namespace std;

    extern int fnu;

    #endif
```

that's the header file avis_h.

The main program goes like this:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    ...
    #include "iostream"
    #include "avis_h.h"


    int fnu;

    int main(){fnu=3;system (app2);}
```

where app2 is the secondary application:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    ...
    #include "iostream"
    #include "avis_h.h"

    int fnu;

    int main(){cout<<fnu;Sleep(10);}
```

instead of the number 3 the number 0 is displayed. I've tried alternative ways but none worked so far. Can somebody please tell me how I get that value passed correctly from the main program to the secondary program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't share variables between independent applications like that.

You can pass it as a parameter to the `system` command:

```
//commandLine is app2 + " " + the parameter
system (commandLine);
```

Breakdown:

```
std::stringstream ss; 
ss << app2; 
ss << " "; 
ss << fnu;
std::string commandLine = ss.str();
system(commandLine.c_str());
```

and don't forget to:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
```

and retrieve it via `argv` in the second application.

Or you can use IPC, but that's overkill in this particular case.

Comment: so this would be system(app2 + " " + fnu) ? Is it the proper syntax?

Comment: @user1331044 well, not exactly. `app2` needs to be a `std::string` and you need to convert `fnu` to a string also (check out `int` to `string` conversion).

Comment: this sounds promising. I'll need some time to work through that, I think about an hour or so. If it works I'll let you know and set the answer as accepted. If not I hope you'll still be around to help. Thx anyway :-)

Comment: yeah, I'm working on it, actually I got to pass six values (string, char, ints, double). But the method is clear, thx to your code. Already got a first success. The number is now 7 instead of 0 although it should be 213 this time :D (fnu is a frame number of an AVI file). But I think your method is going to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Applications have different address spaces and if you wish to pass some data from one application to another you can either write to a file in one application and read the file in another or you can use one of the inter process communication mechanisms supported by the underlying operating system. On Unix-like systems, these mechanisms are pipe, fifo, message queue and shared memory. You can even use sockets. To use the system function is somewhat not very nice. However, if you wish to use system function only, which is workable for this simple inter-process communication, try to pass the value of fnu as a parameter to app2.

```
char buf [20];

sprintf (buf, "app2 %d", fnu);
system (buf);
```

Comment: Writing and reading from a file is the worst possible suggestion for IPC.